# How to post data of logged in user with a form in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am creating a form for users to book times on my web app. Currently I have the following files.

see forms.py:

```
class BookingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    usname = User.username
    daterequired = forms.CharField(max_length=60, required=True)
    students = forms.CharField(max_length=60, required=True)
    length = forms.CharField(max_length=60, required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = "__all__"
```

see models.py:

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    usname = User.username
    daterequired = models.DateField(_("Date"), default=datetime.date.today)
    students = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    length = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
```

see views.py:

```
@login_required
def choose(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BookingForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form = form.save(commit=False)
            form.save()
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = BookingForm()
    return render(request, 'choose.html', {'form': form})
```

What I am trying to achieve is that when a user clicks submit on the form that their user data automatically gets logged in the bookings table on the database. At the minute the only data getting logged in the table is the date field, students and length. I need to know which user is posting this data.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Your form and models make no sense. You can't just do `usname = User.username`; you need an actual field - a ForeignKey - pointing at the User model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the model. The way you have defined `usname` is not valid. Change it to:

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    daterequired = models.DateField(_("Date"), default=datetime.date.today)
    students = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    length = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
```

Then change the form to this:

```
class BookingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        exclude = ['user', ]
```

You don't need to redefine fields if you use `ModelForm`.

Run `makemigrations` and `migrate`. Finally, change code inside `choose()` to:

```
if form.is_valid():
    form = form.save(commit=False)
    form.user = request.user
    form.save()
    return redirect('index')
```

Comment: THIS WORKED! I am a noob to Django in many many ways so this will help a lot moving forward. Thank you so much for your answer!!